# A nabla operator identity in ortho-normal coordinate systems

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $u_1,~u_2,~u_3$ be components of the position vector $\vec{u}$:

$$\vec{u}=u_1 \vec{e}_{u_1}+u_2 \vec{e}_{u_2}+u_3 \vec{e}_{u_3}$$

in an ortho-normal coordinate system (**not necessarily Cartesian**) spun by the ortho-normal basis $\{\vec{e}_{u_1},\vec{e}_{u_2},\vec{e}_{u_3}\}$.

Prove:

$$\nabla\cdot\left(\nabla u_1\times\nabla u_2\right)=0$$

I am mostly interested in the general non-Cartesian case.

Comment: Is $\vec u$ some arbitrary vector field?  Or is it the position vector, and $\nabla$ differentiates with respect to the components of $\vec u$?

Comment: $\vec{u}$ is the position vector. But it is clear, since $\vec{u}$ is explicitated in terms of basis vectors $\vec{e}_{u_i}$. Let me make that more clear in the question above...